# Dynamic runtime in AWS SAM template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

In my SAM template I use variables to set environment etc. and now I'm trying to specify node version to use for the function but it fails. Relevant template parts are below:

```
Parameters:
  Env:
    Type: String
    Description: Select the appropriate environment
    AllowedValues:
      - dev
  NodeVersion:
    Type: String
    Description: Node version to be used

......

      SomeFunction:
        Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
        Properties:
          FunctionName: !Sub my-function-${Env}
          CodeUri: src/
          Handler: index.handler
          Runtime: !Sub ${NodeVersion}
```

I also tried

```
          Runtime: !Sub nodejs${NodeVersion}.x
```

.. and various other combinations, with quotes etc. but always when I run `sam build` it fails with e.g. `Error: 'nodejsNodeVersion.x' runtime is not supported`
Is it possible to set runtime from variables as I do with `Env` and if so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure this is your real code? I do not see how you could get the error you are reporting? But you can try with `Runtime: !Sub "nodejs${NodeVersion}.x"`

Comment: @Marcin found out that to get this working NodeVersion property requires "Default" field e.g."Default: 'nodejs14.x'"